# Running remote script via ssh command

Tags: ssh, debian, path

I have a script on remote Debian server machine and I want to run a command by invoking:

```
ssh server "find.sh"
```

My **find.sh** script is in in:

```
/home/user/bin
```

First of all, I ran **ssh server "echo $PATH"** and it responded with this path:

```
/home/user/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

So it seems that PATH variable is ok but it doesn't work. Only way I could make it work was by invoking full path:

```
ssh server "/home/user/bin/find.sh"
```

Is there any simple way to make it work without specifying full path?

Comment: What is the permission of the find.sh file?  It should be 755.  If is only 644 it will not be executed automagically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to define `$PATH` in your `~/.bashrc` file on target server, at the beginning of the file :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/bin
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940533/how-do-i-set-path-such-that-ssh-userhost-command-works :

> Bash in non-interactive mode reads the file ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 2):

`ssh server "echo $PATH"` is not the same mode of operation as `ssh server "find.sh"`. The first contains shell metacharacters (specifically, a space) and therefore will be run by "sh -c 'specified command'"; the second does not, and therefore will be run by "exec('specified_command')". The difference is subtle, but in this case (because it is the shell which sets the environment variable) has side effects that you may not be expecting.

You can force a shell by doing something like `ssh server 'bash -c "find.sh"'`

Answer (score 2):

Typing `ssh server "echo $PATH"` is going to expand `PATH` locally. So the command you are actually executing is `ssh server "echo /home/user/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"`, and the server will produce the same output every time it receives that command regardless of what `PATH` is on the server side. If you want to expand `PATH` on the server side you can use: `ssh server 'echo "$PATH"'` instead. Notice that single-quotes are being used to prevent local expansion of `$PATH`.

Comment: Good point, I forgot about expansion of "".